# Mac OS X CD ripping speed

Tags: macos, dvd, performance, ripping, applescript

I am using vobcopy (installed via macports) to rip DVDs on a mac. I have been doing this for a while on linux with no problems. On the mac however, it is VERY slow. I am guessing that somehow the DVD drive is being limited to 1x in order to keep noise and power consumption down during playback. Is there a way to over ride this?

Update:
It is MUCH slower than 1x. It has taken me about an hour to copy 300MB

Notes:
While I appreciate all suggestions, I am not looking for "Have you tried HandBrake?". I am looking for a solution to copy the contents of a DVD, not transcode them. Also, I am launching vobcopy from an apple script that gets executed on DVD insertion, so a GUI solution is not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `dd` utility to rip a DVD:

```
dd if=/dev/disk1 of=/path/to/backup.iso
```

if you'd like to gzip them to save space:

```
dd if=/dev/disk1 | gzip -9 > /path/to/backup.dmg.gz
```

The DVD drive is likely `/dev/disk1` or `/dev/disk2` on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried launching it from the terminal just using "vobcopy -m"? That's what I use and it will copy a full dvd in around 30mins.

Answer (score -1):

If vobcopy's man page doesn't help, I'm not sure anything will. OS X and Linux use completely different device/driver models so I wouldn't expect miracles from ported software.